# How to make bokeh toolbar tools inactive by default

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to make all tools in the toolbar inactive? Having pan and wheel-zoom buttons active by default is counterproductive when scrolling in an IPython notebook.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a link to the docs regarding setting active tools on bokeh 0.12.3:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools.

In your case when you define the figure you can just set active_drag and active_scroll to None. For example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
fig = figure(active_drag=None, active_scroll=None)  # no active tools by default
```

Comment: I believe this works for toolbars of individual plots, but not for the merged toolbar of a `gridplot`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the answer yet but you want to define tools as follows in your figure function:

```
p = bp.figure(title='[your title]',tools='')
```

Comment: Thanks! My question was not about defining tools (adding or removing from the toolbar), but how to control which ones are active, that is, have that blue underlining. I want all of them to be initially inactive and only activated when a user clicks on a tool button.